# How can a MenuItem be separated into its own module in Electron?

Tags: menu, electron, menuitem

New to Electron and building menus I'm trying to see if I can separate a `MenuItem` to prevent an enormous file but I'm having issues. For example I've separated the menu code outside of *main.js* and I moved menu in a renderer directory within a Menu directory. I can call the Menu from *main.js* with:

```
let mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(require('./renderer/Menus/mainMenu'))
```

*mainMenu.js*:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        label: 'Foo',
        id: 'itemFoo',
        submenu: [
            {label: 'Enter Foo'},
            {label: 'Exit Foo'}
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'Bar',
        id: 'itemBar',
        submenu: [
            {label: 'Enter Bar'},
            {label: 'Exit Bar'}
        ]
    }   
]
```

and it works but could each menu item be separated further into their own file and what would be the proper way to do that?

I've tried to take *mainMenu.js* and code it as:

```
const foo = require('./itemFoo')

module.exports = [
    {foo},
    {
        label: 'Bar',
        id: 'itemBar',
        submenu: [
            {label: 'Enter Bar'},
            {label: 'Exit Bar'}
        ]
    }   
]
```

itemFoo.js:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        label: 'Foo',
        id: 'itemFoo',
        submenu: [
            {label: 'Enter Foo'},
            {label: 'Exit Foo'}
        ]
    }
]
```

but I get an error:

> TypeError: Invalid template for MenuItem: must have at least one of
>   label, role or type

Can a menu item in Electron be isolated into it's own module and if so how to do it? I didn't see this mentioned when searching [[electron] menuitem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Belectron%5D%20menuitem) or under the [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu-item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was writing the Menu Items incorrectly. It should be:

*main.js:*

```
const { Menu } = require('electron')

let mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(require('./renderer/Menus/mainMenu'))

app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow.createWindow(),
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu)
})
```

*mainMenu.js:*

```
const foo = require('./itemFoo')
const bar = require('./itemBar')

module.exports = [
    foo,
    bar
]
```

*itemBar.js:*

```
module.exports = {
    label: 'Foo',
    id: 'itemFoo',
    submenu: [
        {label: 'Enter Foo'},
        {label: 'Exit Foo'}
    ]
}
```

*itemFoo.js:*

```
module.exports = {
    label: 'Bar',
    id: 'itemBar',
    submenu: [
        {label: 'Enter Bar'},
        {label: 'Exit Bar'}
    ]
}
```

That will allow me to have each main menu item in its own file and clear *main.js*.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (untested though):

**main process**:

```
let mainMenuTemplate =
[
    require('./renderer/Menus/itemFoo'),
    require('./renderer/Menus/itemBar')
];
let mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
```

**itemFoo.js**:

```
module.exports =
{
    label: 'Foo',
    id: 'itemFoo',
    submenu: [
        {label: 'Enter Foo'},
        {label: 'Exit Foo'}
    ]
};
```

**itemBar.js**:

```
module.exports =
{
    label: 'Bar',
    id: 'itemBar',
    submenu: [
        {label: 'Enter Bar'},
        {label: 'Exit Bar'}
    ]
};
```

Note: an intermediate `mainMenu.js` file is probably unnecessary then...