# Menu template in module - context error when calling function

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to move my verbose `Electron` menu template code into its own module and am running into a "context" issue. There is an earlier question ([How can a MenuItem be separated into its own module in Electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55200616/how-can-a-menuitem-be-separated-into-its-own-module-in-electron)) which is related to what I am trying to do but it doesn't address the issue.

My code works – the menu is created – but the specified function calls (e.g. `quitApplication()`) throw errors ("quitApplication() is not a function").

Do I pass in some reference to the `main.js` context or is there a standard way to handle this (or the wrong "this" ;-)

---

**Code below**

my menu module (verbose code removed for clarity)

```
exports.getProjectPickerMenu = function () {
return  [
  {
      label: global.appName,
      submenu: [
          { label: 'About ' + global.appName, click: () => { showAboutWindow() } },
          { type: 'separator' },
          { role: 'hide' },
          { role: 'hideothers' },
          { role: 'unhide' },
          { type: 'separator' },
          { label: 'Quit', click: () => { quitApplication() }, accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+q' },
      ]
  }];
}
```

and I call it like this in `main.js`:

```
const menuTemplates = require("./app/js/menu-templates.js");

Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplates.getProjectPickerMenu()));
```

Comment: In which file is the `quitApplication` function definition located?

Comment: @hijleh - the `quitApplication` function is defined in "main.js". The menu template code was moved to "menuTemplates.js" and is returned with the `menuTemplates.getProjectPickerMenu()` function call. The template is used by  `Menu.buildFromTemplate` which occurs in main.js". I'm baffled.

Comment: "the quitApplication function is defined in main.js".

that's your problem then. `quitApplication` is looked for in `menu-templates.js`

Comment: @hijleh - yes, I understand that. I am looking for a solution.

Comment: Ugly solution but you can pass `quitApplication` to `getProjectPickerMenu`. Like: `Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplates.getProjectPickerMenu(quitApplication)));` and `exports.getProjectPickerMenu = function (quitApplication)`